# Python won't find the class of an HTML table

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to scrape a table on [a webpage](https://experience.arcgis.com/experience/76b68b923a094fb5a2d193ace5ccb975/) into a Python dataframe. The id of the table, upon inspection, is `esri-feature-table__content`. So, I do:

```
import requests as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests as r


page = r.get("https://experience.arcgis.com/experience/76b68b923a094fb5a2d193ace5ccb975/")
pagetext = page.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(pagetext, 'html.parser')


div = soup.find(id = "esri-feature-table__content")
print(div)
```

However, Python prints out "None", when I expect for it to key on the table's rows and columns. When I do

```
soup.find_all("table")
```

the list of tables is empty. How might I solve this?

Comment: There's an option to export all the data to various formats (JSON or CSV, for example) - so why do you need to scrape the tabel?

Comment: By the way, you can't *find* the table because it's not there in the HTML. It's dynamically loaded by JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, Selenium (my first method) was the answer. Now that I look at it again, this is the way to do it:

```
import time, os
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
preferences= {"download.default_directory": os.getcwd(), "directory_upgrade": True}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", preferences)
options.headless = True

url = "https://experience.arcgis.com/experience/76b68b923a094fb5a2d193ace5ccb975/"

# Path of my WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)

#get method to launch the URL
driver.get(url)


paths = ["#page_0 > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div.flex-shrink-0.flex-grow-1.d-flex.app-root-emotion-cache-ltr-d56pf2 > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div.horizontal-render-con > div.top-button-list > div.top-button.data-action-btn > div > div > button",
"body > div.popper.inner-popper.jimu-dropdown-menu.dropdown-menu.show.app-root-emotion-cache-ltr-1n8muf3 > div > div > div > button > span.dropdown-button-content > div > span",
"body > div:nth-child(28) > div > div > button:nth-child(2)", 
"body > div:nth-child(27) > div > div.modal.jimu-outline-inside.fade.show > div > div > div.modal-footer > button.jimu-btn.app-root-emotion-cache-ltr-1rus8bb.btn.btn-primary"]

for x in paths:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, x))).click()
```

Presumably, there's a cleaner way to do this. But, this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Use [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/), Luke**

Selenium supports automation of all the major browsers in the market through the use of WebDriver.

Comment: Yeah Selenium was the first thing I tried. I'll edit the post and post the code as to why that didn't work for me.

Comment: As I know, the Selenium is the first thing to parse js-ed HTML page.
There are a thousand reasons for going wrong, for example the "User agent" string value.
Another way is to load Javascript's scripts and parse its.